# SSIS skip dataflow task if it takes too much time

Tags: ssis

I'm creating a ssis package that's supposed to transfer data from a database to another. However, if the dataflow task takes too much time to perform, i want it to stop and go ahead with the other tasks.

I've already tried to set the `CommandTimeout` property to the dataflow source, but the dataflow task doesn't stop running.

Comment: There is probably a complicated solution that we could think up - put the dataflow in a package, call the package from a script task, add a timeout condition to the script task to kill the process.  However, which you be open to optimizing the loading process?

Comment: Well, if there's no other solution i guess i'll have to go with yours. By the way, the loading process is already optimized, it's the source database that's poorly designed: tables with millions of records with no indexing at all.. So, since it's not important data i decided that if takes too much time i would discard it and move on

Comment: You might also call a bat file that executes the package.  This can run asynchronously in its own process - so just kick it off and let it run while the rest of the package executes.

Comment: Thanks again, but the real problem is: why doesn't the task stop if i set the commandtimeout property? Before tryng these workarounds you suggested, i wanted to know what's wrong with my settings..

Comment: Because the commandtimeout only governs how long the package will wait for the source command to return results.   It doesn't have anything to say about how long it takes those results to get processed through the rest of the dataflow.

Comment: Ok, but if i say "You have 30 seconds to return result", shouldn't after 30 seconds move on to the next task? I'm clearly missing something but i don't get it

Answer (score 1):

> why doesn't the task stop if i set the commandtimeout property?

I am guessing that SSIS calls the READ method each time it writes to the buffer at the source component.  The commandtimeout is reset with every call to the read method.  There is some info on that here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

So the source needs to be slow enough not to return any rows for the commandtimeout period.  This does not sound like it will work for your scenario.

Alternatives suggested are:

- Put the dataflow in another package

  - call the package from a script task
  - cause the process to timeout after a set period in the script
- Or, put the dataflow in another package

  - call the package from a bat file and just let it run in it's own process until when ever it finishes.

I understand that the source system does not have proper indexing which makes reading a slow process.  It sounds like there are multiple tables, you could consider reading them all individually and staging them on the target server.  This could avoid a bad query plan that might be resulting from JOINs.  Also, do insure that the table(s) you are writing to are not a bottleneck - remove indexes, constraints, add tablock.